# On StackApps.com the /admin route ends in a server error

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, 500-server-error, stackapps

I just tried to visit the [Stack Apps Mod dashboard](https://stackapps.com/admin) but that ends in an

> Oops! Something Bad Happened!

and it is all your fault. At least that is what it says in the next paragraph.

I checked with a fellow moderator and they experienced the same error. Other moderators on other sites report no problems.

I know Stack Apps is special and we appreciated our little different features here and there. Still, this error is a bit hindering our moderation duties.

Would you mind looking into this and if possible resolve the issue?

Comment: I mean, really - do you need it? It's just where you can go to check up on the other moderator's actions and report yourself as being on vacation... you don't... go on vacation, do you??? :P

Comment: @Catija I was about to ask for 6 to 8 days off ... I get the message .... maybe next year ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We apologize for the fault in the /admin page loading. Those responsible have been sacked.

Okay, not really, but we did have a user (who also happens to be an SE employee) who ended up with two profiles linked to the same account id, so the /admin page (which also shows diamonded employee activity) was erroring out. Try as valiantly as we might, C# just won't let us put the same number twice as a key into a dictionary.

Comment: Can you please explain why you removed the link to the bug report?