# Awkward text wrap for recording moderator absence

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, moderator-tools, moderation-history

In the moderator dashboard, there's an option to record yourself as absent / inactive. There's a checkbox to have this apply on all sites you moderate, but its label is wrapped awkwardly; "on all" appears on the far right and "sites I moderate" on the next line all the way to the left. I feel like the textbox can make some room, or otherwise move the checkbox and the label to the next line.

[image: screenshot from moderator dashboard]

(Firefox on macOS, 13" MacBook Pro - this page isn't fully responsive yet so YMMV.)

Comment: That label seems to need a css rule: `display : inline-block;`. That will move the checkbox and text completely  under the button / inputbox when  there is not enough width left.

Comment: Repeating what Catija said earlier [*you don't... go on vacation, do you???*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379741/on-stackapps-com-the-admin-route-ends-in-a-server-error#comment1266995_379741)

Comment: Have the updates to the /admin page fixed this for you? (I can't actually see the button)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Catija indicates, recent updates have fixed this. The checkbox has been moved to a separate fully responsive dialog:

[image]

Ironically, I couldn't confirm it until now, because I was on holiday for three weeks ...